# How do I *not* use Docker for a given Gitlab CI job?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm using the shared Gitlab runners, and I have an Alpine based image that manages Terraform and Ansible repositories for cloud management. In the first stage, I use `docker:dind` instead to build the builder image (which is working fine), but all other stages use this built image, and have no further business consulting docker for anything. However, I'm still receiving this error when GitLab CI runs `docker info`:

> ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Here's an abbreviated version of my .gitlab-ci.yml file, with an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
stages:
  - image
  - validate

image-job:
  stage: image
  image: docker:dind
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: {{ sanitized_value }}
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG ci-support
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG

validate-job:
  stage: validate
  image: $IMAGE_TAG
  environment: production
  interacts_with_docker: false    # <-- This is what I'm trying to do
  script:
    - terraform plan
    - ansible-playbook --check some-playbook.yaml
```

As an alternative solution, I'm also willing to accept answers that configure docker-cli (without a full daemon, preferably) to pull docker info from the docker service provided to the image job, to allow the job to continue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as it turns out, existed between the keyboard and the chair. I naively assumed `docker info` was being run by GitLab CI core, when it was in the before script.

That's what I get for copying and pasting things before coffee. :)